# Why, when I initWithObjects an NSArray, does it end up empty?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsarray

I'm a newbie, so I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out to be something stupid, but I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure out why the NSArray haikuArray, after I try to initWithObjects, never contains any objects.  Any thoughts?

Gay_HaikuViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Array Setup.h"

@interface Gay_HaikuViewController : UIViewController
{
Array_Setup *gayHaikuSetup;
Array_Setup *userHaikuSetup;
NSMutableArray *allHaiku;
IBOutlet UITextView *haikuText;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) Array_Setup *gayHaikuSetup;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Array_Setup *userHaikuSetup;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *allHaiku;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *haikuText;
-(IBAction)nextHaiku:(id)sender;
```

Relevant method in Gay_HaikuViewController.m file:

```
#import "Gay_HaikuViewController.h"
#import "Array Setup.h"

@interface Gay_HaikuViewController ()

@end

@implementation Gay_HaikuViewController

@synthesize gayHaikuSetup,userHaikuSetup,allHaiku,haikuText;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *haikuArray = [gayHaikuSetup arrayOfGayHaiku];
haikuArray = [gayHaikuSetup readFromGayArray];
//This next line is how I know there are no objects in haikuArray.
NSLog(@"%d",[haikuArray count]);
NSMutableArray *userArray = [userHaikuSetup arrayOfUserHaiku];
userArray = [userHaikuSetup readFromUserArray];
allHaiku = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[haikuArray count]; i++)
    [allHaiku addObject:[haikuArray objectAtIndex:i]];
for (int i=0; i<[userArray count]; i++)
    [allHaiku addObject:[userArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Array_Setup.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Array_Setup : NSObject
{
NSMutableArray *arrayOfUserHaiku;
NSArray *arrayOfGayHaiku;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfUserHaiku;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *arrayOfGayHaiku;

-(NSArray *)readFromGayArray;
-(NSMutableArray *)readFromUserArray;
-(NSMutableArray *)writeToUserArray;
-(void)addHaikuToArray;

@end
```

And the relevant methods in Array_Setup.m file:

```
#import "Array Setup.h"

@implementation Array_Setup

@synthesize arrayOfGayHaiku,arrayOfUserHaiku;

-(NSMutableArray *)readFromUserArray
{
arrayOfUserHaiku = [NSMutableArray alloc];
[arrayOfUserHaiku initWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/cool.txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (!arrayOfUserHaiku)
{
    NSLog(@"Read failed: %@.",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"cool.txt looks like this: %@.",arrayOfUserHaiku);
}
return arrayOfUserHaiku;
}

-(NSArray *)readFromGayArray
{
NSArray *array = [NSArray alloc];
[array initWithObjects:@"Lorem", @"ipsum", nil]; 

return array;
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance for your help, guys and gals.

Comment: Please edit out the text in the array with lorem ipsum. People may find it offensive.

Comment: Better yet shorten it to one line, as it is not necessary for the code to function.

Comment: Done.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serious problems in this code:

```
arrayOfUserHaiku = [NSMutableArray alloc];
[arrayOfUserHaiku initWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/cool.txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (!arrayOfUserHaiku)
{
    NSLog(@"Read failed: %@.",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"cool.txt looks like this: %@.",arrayOfUserHaiku);
}
return arrayOfUserHaiku;
}
```

1. Never split the `alloc` and the `init`.   `init` methods will sometimes (often, actually) not return the same object that `alloc` returned.   I.e. that should be:

   arrayOfUserHaiku = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/cool.txt"];
2. `error` isn't going to be set by anything in that code ever;  it isn't a global.
3. That method should return an autoreleased array (assuming non-ARC).
4. You should avoid large arrays of static strings in your code.  Put 'em into the app wrapper as a plist or text file that can be localized easily.

(And, as the commenter suggested, don't put your app's contents into the question -- some might find it offensive)

Comment: Thanks for all these.  I'm using ARC, but I've implemented the rest of your suggestions and it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`initWithObjects` returns a value, but you're not setting `array` to the return value.

Comment: Okay.  Forgive me for not understanding, but what's the value `initWithObjects` returns?  I tried doing `initWithObjects:count:` but kept getting an error message demanding a `:` before `count`, which didn't make any sense--and when I added it, it just produced another error message.

Comment: @JoelDerfner: The return value is the object that has been initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Array_Setup.m file:

```
   #import "Array_Setup.h"

@implementation Array_Setup

@synthesize arrayOfGayHaiku,arrayOfUserHaiku;

-(NSMutableArray *)readFromUserArray
{
    arrayOfUserHaiku = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/cool.txt"];
 //   [arrayOfUserHaiku initWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/cool.txt"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (!arrayOfUserHaiku)
    {
        NSLog(@"Read failed: %@.",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"cool.txt looks like this: %@.",arrayOfUserHaiku);
    }
    return arrayOfUserHaiku;
}

-(NSArray *)readFromGayArray
{
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"I don't understand.\nYou love it when I do that--\nWait, no.  That's Stephen.",

     @"Frantically hiding\nPorno and Mapplethorpe prints--\nMom is on her way.",

     @"Remember when I\nSaid I disliked oral sex?\nI meant just with you.",

     @"You were perfection.\nThen you misspelled 'embarrassed.'\nDon't call me again.",

     //Am omitting a bunch of these to make my Stack Overflow question shorter.

     @"I know you think I\nLike it when you slap my ass.\nYou are mistaken.",

     @"Flailing to the beat--\nCould I possibly look half\nAs dumb as I feel?",

     @"Last night, you looked hot.\nToday, you want to discuss\nThe whole foods movement.", nil]; 

    return array;
}

@end
```

Gay_HaikuViewController.m file:

```
userHaikuSetup= [[Array_Setup alloc] init];

gayHaikuSetup= [[Array_Setup alloc] init]; // [gayHaikuSetup arrayOfGayHaiku];

NSArray * haikuArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [gayHaikuSetup readFromGayArray]];
//This next line I added to find out whether the array had any objects--I always get 0.
NSLog(@"%lu",[haikuArray count]);

NSMutableArray *userArray = [userHaikuSetup readFromUserArray];
allHaiku = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[haikuArray count]; i++)
    [allHaiku addObject:[haikuArray objectAtIndex:i]];
for (int i=0; i<[userArray count]; i++)
    [allHaiku addObject:[userArray objectAtIndex:i]];


NSLog(@"%lu",[allHaiku count]);
```

This can run;you should see some objective-c Program syntax book 。

Comment: See my answer;  your code might run, but that doesn't make it correct.  And your answer lacks explanations.